# New tab in a jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to know if there is a way to open a new tab in this situation:

I have a table in a page with customers (searchCustomer.jsf)

On each row I have a command link to edit this particular customer.

The code for the command link is this one:

```html
<p:column styleClass="buttonColumn"  exportable="false" >
   <p:commandLink title="#{msg.set}"
      action="#{searchCustomerManageBean.setCustomer(customer)}"
      disabled="#{ not searchCustomerManageBean.canEdit(customer)}"
      value="#{msg.edit}"/>                   
</p:column>
```

in the managed bean I have the setCustomer function:

```html
 public String setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        
        setcustomerSelected(customer);
        final DataTable d1 = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:basicDT");
        int first1 = d1.getFirst();
        actualPage = first1;       
        WebUtils.putObjectOnFlashContext("customerId", customer.getCustomerId());
        WebUtils.putObjectOnFlashContext("Back page", "GO_TO_CUSTOMER_SEARCH");
        WebUtils.putObjectOnFlashContext("read only", Boolean.FALSE);
        return "GO_TO_CUSTOMER";
    }
```

I have set up the pages in my faces-config.xml

```html
faces-config.xml

<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>GO_TO_CUSTOMER_SEARCH</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/pages/searchCustomer.jsf</to-view-id>
  <redirect/>
</navigation-case>


<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>GO_TO_CUSTOMER</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/pages/manageCustomer.jsf</to-view-id>
  <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

If I just click on the link, the function does what I want. (The page go to manageCustomer.jsf);

but if I try to open the link in a new tab(rigth click ->open in an new tab) (the page go back to my searchCustomer.jsf)

Is there a way to make this last option(open in a new tab) works same as the first option(click the link)?

please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. At least not without refactoring your code.

When you select `new tab` from the browsers context-menu, all the browser does is:

- Copy the target-url
- Open it in a new tab.

and since (html-technically) your link would point to `/pages/searchCustomer.jsf` - you'll end up on the first page again.

The only way to handle this is designing deep-links for your application. i.e. your "manage" button should refer to the URL `/pages/manageCustomer.jsf?customer_id=5988`, where you use `<f:viewParam name="customer_id" value="#{bean.selectedCustomerId} />` to put the url-parameter `customer_id` back into a bean-property to do further processing.

But using this will kill the point of using partial-responses on jsf-webapps, as it would end up with a request/response-model in order to fetch the GET-Parameters.

If used for internal purpose, teach your people, that a web-app is not a web-site, so different rules apply :-)

I mean: You also can't just open a "submit-button" of any POST-Form (vanilla-html) in a new-tab. It also won't work. Everybody got this, so it's just a question of habit. Change your links to "Buttons" and no one would ever expect to be able to open it in a new tab.